# Basic elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I just enrolled in a class called "Elementary Number Theory" and I am left confused in every class due to the different notations and proofs shown.

Is there a really basic book on Number Theory out there that I can read to nail down the basics of this course?

Thanks.

Comment: There is also a question "Best number theory book" with a vote score of 100 right now that might be useful. Please be sure to do a search before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

David M. Burton's elementary number theory is the "best" for elementary treatment. Also, Elementary number theory in nine chapters by James Tattersall is also very nice.

But if you want to know what is really "basic" you should prefer The Number Systems: Foundations of Algebra and Analysis by solomon feferman